# Importing Alamofire 3.4 - No such module 'Alamofire'

Tags: xcode, swift, git, alamofire

I hava a project that need Alamofire imported and every aproach i took got me to same porblem 
import Alamofire - No such module 'Alamofire'

- Installed cocoapods
- Edited Podfile:

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'my project name' do

    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'

end
```

`$ pod install`

everything was smooth and had no errors in the proces from installing cocoapods to the end.

Opened project with projectname.xcworkspace

Even tried the manually and still the same problem - No such module 'Alamofire'

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `import Alamofire` and then do `Build`. I think it's helpful.

Comment: Did that and project still failed to build :(

Comment: did you install Cocoapods on the route of your computer, if you did that do pod setup and try clean and build?

Comment: problem was that Alamofire 3.4 had some issuess with xcode beta and now when i updated it it runs as it should, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After adding a framework through `CocoaPods`, in most conditions you are supposed to clean and build the project right away.

That should take care of adding/building the new framework to your app and make it active for use

Also, please note that another copy of your project will be created upon addition with pods, called something like '`yourProjectName.xcworkspace`' (You can find it in your directory). It will have a light blue color thumbnail. After adding your pods, you must start using that copy of your project instead of the normal project.

// **Note** : Generally with `CocoaPods`, when you add a pod to your `Podfile`, you just need to save the `Podfile` and type 'podinstall' in your terminal. Make sure to get to your project directory before that. That will import the frameworks automatically. However, you do need to write import statement in your file to use it obviously

You **do not** need to import Alamofire framework explicitly (if using Cocoa Pods) - Umair (in comments)

Comment: Do we explicitly need to import framework after installing it with CocoaPods ?

Comment: nope.. generally with cocoaPods, when you add pod to your podfile, you just need to save the podfile and do 'podinstall' in your terminal. That imports the frameworks automatically. However, you need to write import statement in your file to use it obviously

Comment: So include it in your answer that we do not need to import Alamofire, I think it would be helpful

Comment: Done as you sad cause that is why how i dod it and still nothing :(
Did import Alamofire in code and then i got good old "No such modul" :(

Comment: @Koljane in your linked binaries, removed pods.framework. That might be it

Comment: I have found the problem. After upgrading xcode to 7.3.1 and did the build everything started to work.
My guess that Alamofire 3.4 had problem working with xcode 7.3 beta.
Anyway thanks a lot for trying to help.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it following the below listed steps:

1. Realized that `<projectName>.xcworkspace` is what you need to be using after adding a pod to your project
2. Deleted the `pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` and did a `pod install`
3. Set `Architectures` to `Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)`
4. Set `Build Active Architectures Only` to `Yes`

Answer (score 1):

I Faced the Same Issue During the Implementation

Step 1 :

> `Import Alamofire`

Step 2 :

> Keep on Pressing Build ( `Cmd + B` )

Step 3:

> If Issue Continues then just close your program for a moment by
>   completely closing it(`cmd + Q`) and then Restart it and Follow Step
>   1 & 2

This will work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you install dependencies using Pods, and if you are working using `.xcodeproj` file, it will never build prompting `no such module` error. You should definetely switch to `.xcworkspace` and you will see everything's fine. If the error persists, you should clean the project or delete derived data.