# No Such module 'Alamofire',but I have pod it already

Tags: ios, swift, module, cocoapods, bridging-header

[image: No Such module 'Alamofire']

As the above picture, when I click the `EvoRadio.xcworkspace` and run the applictaion, it warns me that `No Such module 'Alamofire'`,`No Such module‘ObjectMapper’`……,but I have already pod them with `CocoaPods`.

**Pod Steps:**

(1) `pod init`

(2)Edit the podfile as follows: 
[image: Podfile]

(3) `pod install`

And I have create a bridging header file (`EvoRadio-Bridging-Header.h`) and set the `Objective-C Bridging header` path:`/Users/ringo/Desktop/EvoRadio-master/EvoRadio/Resources/EvoRadio-Bridging-Header.h`

I have searched the issue on stackoverflow and found [Importing Alamofire 3.4 - No such module 'Alamofire'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743680/importing-alamofire-3-4-no-such-module-alamofire),but it didn't help me.

I'm wondering why it happened and how to solve it ?

Comment: check if you have this line in your pod file     use_frameworks!

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have checked the pod file, and it contained  use_frameworks.Is it correct?

Comment: yes its ok then

Comment: Can you show your podfile?

Comment: @user1000 Ok ,I will edit the question with the podfile screenshot.

Comment: clean your project and try again, and clean with command alt + k

Comment: clean your project and build it again and make sure your current running device is not lower then 9.0 IOS

Comment: Cleaned the project and built it again, but the issue still existed. I removed all the pods and pod them again, it works now.Thanks all.

Comment: have you open workspace?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya Of course, I did.

Comment: @OmniRingo make your project deep clean by cmd+Shift+K

Comment: @OmniRingo Please try with writing "pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'" and install the cocoa pods?

Comment: @NilayShah Thanks for ur reply, I removed all the pods and re-pod them again, it works. It's so strange.

Comment: If its working then accept the answer and give upvote for the same. So other SO visitors can apply in their code for solving their issues. Thank you.

Comment: @OmniRingo Check Linked FrameWorks and Libraries in General. Try remove the podfile framework and add again. Clean the project and Build again.

Comment: @Sudhi9135 Yeah, I have cleaned the project and build it again when I came across the case,but it was still there. Finally, I removed all the pods and pod install again,it worked! So weird.

Comment: @OmniRingo Sometimes Pod installation is a weird process is there any updates. Anyway it worked. Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "**pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5**" and install the cocoa pods again. I think it will be working fine.

Due to conflicts the versions of cocoa pods, some time these types of issues are occurs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.But the case was that not only warning the inexistence of the Alamofire module ,but also other modules(which I have described in the question).So I didn't think it was related to the version of Alamofire. I tried to clean and build, but without success.Finally, I removed all the pods and pod install them again,it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have such problem, and i solve this by cleaning and rebuilding my project.

Just click on up xcode menu Product -> Clean , Product -> Build after

If this doesn't help try press Alt and then Product -> Clean Build Folder

Product -> Build after